# Extracting DATA from a string using PHP

Tags: php, extract

I have a URL which contains some data. I need to extract its data separately. I managed to get this done correctly but the problem is that the URL keeps changing its data order making my code useless. Please help me.

Here is my codes:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("https://stats.vatsim.net/user_count_json.php");
$res = explode(",", "$html");
$res1 = explode(":", "$res[1]");
$res2 = explode(":", "$res[2]");
$res3 = explode(":", "$res[3]");
$res4 = explode(":", "$res[4]");
$res5 = explode(":", "$res[5]");
$res6 = explode(":", "$res[6]");
$pilots = explode( '""', trim( $res1[1], '"'));
$controllers = explode( '""', trim( $res2[1], '"'));
$atis = explode( '""', trim( $res3[1], '"'));
$observers = explode( '""', trim( $res4[1], '"'));
$total = explode( '""', trim( $res5[1], '"'));
$supervisors = explode( '""', trim( $res6[1], '"'));
?>
<h3 style="margin-left: 80px; margin-top: 75px;">Vatsim online users</h3>

<div id="vs" style="border: solid 3px; padding: 25px; border-radius: 5px;"    class="container">
<ul class="blocklist">
    <li>Pilots : <?php echo $pilots[0];?></li>
    <li>Controllers : <?php echo $controllers[0];?></li>
    <li>Atis : <?php echo $atis[0];?></li>
    <li>Observers : <?php echo $observers[0];?></li>
    <li>Supervisors : <?php echo $supervisors[0];?></li>
    <li>Total : <?php echo $total[0];?></li>        

</ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is there something wrong with `json_decode`?

Comment: Learn how to use `json`

Comment: Use `json_decode` and ask yourself why you are putting your arrays inside double quotes.

Comment: @CBroe Then why are they publish the data if they don't want me to use them?

Comment: @kainaw: it's called cargo-cult programming.

Comment: @ParvizKhorraminejad: because it's YOU who are misreading the data. they're sending json, which is a perfectly valid/common data exchange format. you're choosing to parse that json manually, when you could have save yourself a LOT of pain/agony by simply using `json_decode()` and getting yourself a standard PHP data structure.

Comment: Guys, I feel like i'm being judged here for not knowing json. :(

Comment: @ParvizKhorraminejad This is not an issue of not knowing JSON. It is an issue of seeing "JSON" in the URL and not typing "JSON" into the search box in the PHP documentation website. The first step for learning any language is to learn to use the documentation website.

Comment: @kainaw point taken. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you're attempting to get data from is a [`JSON`](http://developers.squarespace.com/what-is-json/) string.  You can convert it into a PHP variable using the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://stats.vatsim.net/user_count_json.php");
$data = json_decode($json, true); //The true parameter will convert the return value into an associative array

//Access Data
$pilots = $data['pilots'];
$controllers = $data['controllers'];
//...etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, start with understanding what is json  - [json.org](http://json.org)

Next, as `json` is a popular data format, all languages support it. In php it's [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) and [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) functions and [others](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

For your case it is:

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://stats.vatsim.net/user_count_json.php");
$array = json_decode($html, true);
print_r($array);
var_dump($array['observers']);   // value of observers field.
```